# Where did snd-aloop go?

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, alsa, kernel-module

I'm on arch linux and I've been using `snd-aloop` to create a virtual audio devices without issues for a year now. Since yesterday's system upgrade to the new Linux kernel (`4.18.3`) however, the module doesn't seem to exist anymore:

```
$ sudo modprobe snd-aloop
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.3-arch1-1-ARCH
$ sudo modprobe snd_aloop
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.3-arch1-1-ARCH
$ modinfo snd-aloop
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias snd-aloop not found.
$ modinfo snd_aloop
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias snd_aloop not found.
```

I've tried `alsactl restore -P` as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891445/alsa-snd-aloop-kernel-module-for-16-04-or-14-04-server/893866#893866) suggestion, but it didn't change anything.

I do not want to use pulseaudio's `module-null-sink` as it uses a lot more CPU power.

Is the `snd-aloop` module deprecated and removed or am I just missing something else? I tried googling `"snd-aloop"` and setting a time range of `last month`, but the 8 results for that have nothing to do with my question and nothing indicated that the module got removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out why after I already wrote the question. In hopes that it helps someone else:

While `uname -a` tells me the kernel I use is `4.18.3` - I actually upgraded to `4.18.5`. I found that out by running the following command:

```
$ ls /lib/modules
4.18.5-arch1-1-ARCH  extramodules-ARCH
```

The folder prefix `4.18.5` reveals that the new kernel version is `4.18.5`, which however isn't in effect until you perform a reboot which is why `modprobe` is looking for kernel modules in a folder that doesn't even exist anymore.

A reboot fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Nearly 10 yrs of experience has taught me the one thing that most Linux users eventually figure out:-

Very few system 'actions' in Linux actually require a re-boot to implement (Windows seems to do this for absolutely everything). Kernel upgrades - or anything kernel-related - are one of the relatively few actions that DO require one.

Oh, and of course there's the other one: You have to be very precise about what you're asking the system to do!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).